# What's the pKa (range) of a carbonyl functional group?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

Why is a $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ value for carbonyls never mentioned anywhere in textbooks I've use while other functional groups have these values?

Comment: Are you talking about aldehydes or enolisable ketones?

Comment: I guess ketones, although information about both would be nice.

Comment: I can't believe they're not mentioned, but look for enols instead ;)

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking about the $\mathrm{pK_a}$ of the $\alpha$ hydrogens or the $\mathrm{pK_a}$ of hydrogens attached directly to the carbonyl carbon?

Comment: Directly attached to the carbonyl carbon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments you are asking for the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ value of a hydrogen *directly attached to a carbonyl carbon.* This means, you are asking only for non-enolisable aldehydes as ketones have no hydrogens on the carbonyl carbon. Aldehydes that have a hydrogen in α-position will be deprotonated there generating an enolate ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} \approx 20$) — more acidic than a carbonyl hydrogen. So all we have left is 2,2-dimethylpropanal (or pivaloylaldehyde). Its $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ is not given on SciFinder, but should be somewhere between $45$ (an alkane) and $25$ (an alkyne), probably just slightly higher than an alkene ($40$).